# Avoid "broken pipe" message

Tags: bash, sed

Is there a way to avoid this message in a command like the following?

```
tac myfile | sed '/abc/q'
```

I understand why the message occurs: sed exits when it finds 'abc' and tac has no where else to send its data. But I would like a way to tell Bash "it's OK, I expect this to happen."

Comment: redirect stderr to devnull?

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr good idea, but I still want to know if there is a different error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disabling `SIGPIPE` should do it:

```
trap -- '' PIPE
```

Comment: Could you please explain the consequences of doing the above? Does this affect execution in any way, or efficiency?

Comment: @XuWang The above just disables the signal, there are no other consequences.

Comment: OK thank you. So disabling the signal means that bash will never receive the signal and thus will not report the error? Actually who reports the error in the first place, bash or the command `tac`?

Comment: @XuWang "Disabling" the signal means `bash` receives the signal and it does nothing in response.  The signal is sent by the kernel.

Comment: Ah I see. One more question: How can I restore things to how they were before after I run the command I have in my OP? (the command is part of a larger script).

Comment: @XuWang `trap - PIPE`

Comment: @SatoKatsura: strictly speaking it is not that `bash` does nothing.  The `tac` process gets the SIGPIPE, *not* `bash`.  However, when `bash` creates the `tac` child process the SIGPIPE handler is set to SIG_IGN in the signal mask, and the signal mask is inherited by the child processes.  This is the way `nohup` works as well.